# Getting and Setting a data attribute in HTML

Tags: javascript

I have an edit box, defined like this:

```
<input class="change-handled form-control" type-id="@sub.CategoryTypeId" sub-category-id="@sub.SubCategoryId" data-id="@sub.CategoryBudgetId" style="text-align: right; width: 100%" type="number" value="@(sub.BudgetAmount.HasValue ? sub.BudgetAmount.ToString() : "")" />
```

In Javascript, I get the data-id value successfully like this:

```
var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

I now need to set it to a different value. I am trying:

```
   $(this).setAttribute("data-id", 5);
```

But it seems the data-id never gets set to the value I pass. How can I set the data-id value of my editbox?

Full code of the function being used. (Note, no error checking yet):

```
$('body').on('change', 'input.change-handled', UpdateTotals);

function UpdateTotals() {
    var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var categoryId = $(this).attr('sub-category-id');
    var value = $(this).val();

    var totalExp = 0;
    var totalInc = 0;

    var $changeInputs = $('input.change-handled');

    $changeInputs.each(function (idx, el) {
        if ($(el).attr('type-id') == 2) {
            totalInc += Number($(el).val());
        }
        if ($(el).attr('type-id') == 1) {
            totalExp += Number($(el).val());
        }
    });

     $(this).val(numberWithCommas(value));

    $('#budgettedExpenseValue').text(numberWithCommas(totalExp));
    $('#budgettedIncomeValue').text(numberWithCommas(totalInc));
    $('#budgettedAvailableValue').text(numberWithCommas(totalInc - totalExp));

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveBudgetValue", "Budget")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ budgetCategoryId: dataId, catgoryId: categoryId, month: 4, year: 2015, value: value }),
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {

            if (result.Success == 'true') {
                $(this).attr("data-id", result.Id);

                alert("Saved! " + result.Id.toString());
            } else {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Oh no...");
        }

    });
```

The code, after an edit box of the class type is edited, sums up all the income boxes (Decorated with a type-id = 1), and updates a field, and all the expense boxes (type-id = 2) and updates a separate field.

It then saves the data with a json call to my controller. If it's a new entry, data-id would have been NULL. The save method returns the primary key of the value saved. That value is displayed in my alert, and is supposed to be assigned to the edit boxe's data-id. But - isn't.

Comment: You can simply try `$(this).attr('data-id', 5)`....

Comment: I am trying that now, but no joy. Should the data-id attribute be updated, when I view the page in Chrome's debugger? It is still data-id="" when I view it.

Comment: Firstly check, are you getting the correct `selector` in `$(this)`..

Comment: Yes, the 'value' and 'data-id', when set, are correct. When I load the screen, and there is a database row for the grid (Some don't have any data yet), then the PK is assigned to the data-id, and I am able to update the row to the database. When it's a new item that has never been saved, initiall, data-id is blank. When I save it, the row gets saved to the database. The reply from the json call returns the PK, which I am trying to assign to the text box's data-id, unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Re your update**

The problem is that in the `ajax` success callback, `this` doesn't refer to the element anymore.

Two ways to fix that, and a third way that will be available in ES6:

1. Assign `this`, or more usefully `$(this)`, to a variable that you use in the success handler (and elsewhere, no need to constantly call `$()` repeatedly on the same element):

   ```
   function UpdateTotals() {
       var input = $(this); // <========== Save it here

       // ...

       $.ajax({
           // ...
           success: function (result) {
               // ...
               if (result.Success == 'true') {
                   input.attr("data-id", result.Id); // <========= Use it here

                   alert("Saved! " + result.Id.toString());
               } else {
                   alert("Failed");
               }
           }
       });

       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Use `Function#bind` (an ES5 feature, but it can be shimmed for really old browsers) to make `this` within the callback the same as `this` outside it:

   ```
   function UpdateTotals() {

       // ...

       $.ajax({
           // ...
           success: function (result) {
               // ...
               if (result.Success == 'true') {
                   $(this).attr("data-id", result.Id);

                   alert("Saved! " + result.Id.toString());
               } else {
                   alert("Failed");
               }
           }.bind(this) // <=========== Note
       });

       // ...
   }
   ```
3. In ES6, we'll have *arrow functions*, which unlike normal functions inherit the `this` of the context in which they're created. So in ES6, you could do this:

   ```
   // **ES6 ONLY**
   function UpdateTotals() {

       // ...

       $.ajax({
           // ...
           success: (result) => {  // <==== Arrow function syntax
               // ...
               if (result.Success == 'true') {
                   $(this).attr("data-id", result.Id);

                   alert("Saved! " + result.Id.toString());
               } else {
                   alert("Failed");
               }
           }
       });

       // ...
   }
   ```

I'd lean toward #1, because you're doing a lot of repeated `$(this)` anyway, so just as well to do `var input = $(this);` *once* and then use `input` throughout.

More about `this` on my blog:

- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

---

**Original answer** pre-update:

Since you're using jQuery, you set an attribute with [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr), like this:

```
$(this).attr("data-id", 5);
```

Live Example:

```js
var input = $("input");
snippet.log("Before: " + input.attr("data-id"));
input.attr("data-id", 5);
snippet.log("After (jQuery): " + input.attr("data-id"));
snippet.log("After (DOM): " + input[0].getAttribute("data-id"));
snippet.log("Element's HTML (after): " + input[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<input class="change-handled form-control" type-id="@sub.CategoryTypeId" sub-category-id="@sub.SubCategoryId" data-id="@sub.CategoryBudgetId" style="text-align: right; width: 100%" type="number" value="@(sub.BudgetAmount.HasValue ? sub.BudgetAmount.ToString() : "")" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Or you can just use the DOM directly, by *not* wrapping the element in a jQuery wrapper:

```
this.setAttribute("data-id", 5);
```

Note that in either case, even though you're giving a number as the value, the value will end up being a string (as attributes only store strings).

---

You'll get people telling you to use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data), but `data` is **not** just a way to access `data-*` attributes, even though many people make that mistake. It *might* be useful for your end goal, though, depending on what that is. The jQuery `data` function manages a cache of data that it associates with the element. The values `data` manages are *initialized* from `data-*` attributes, but `data` never *writes* to `data-*` attributes. If you're just trying to update attribute values, use `attr`. If you're trying to do something more complex and it's not important that the values get written back to the element as attributes, look at the docs for `data` and see whether it might be useful for you. (For one thing, the values `data` manages can be types other than strings.)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Learned new thing today. So what is better to use `data()` or `attr()`?

Comment: @Manwal: Neither is better, it totally depends on what you want to do. If it's important that you update the actual attribute (for instance, if you're going to use it in a selector later to find the element, or some library is going to read the attribute to do something with it, etc.), you have to use `attr` (or the DOM's `setAttribute`) because `data` won't do that. If you're trying to store rich data associated with an element that *doesn't* have to be in an attribute, `data` might be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot, T.J. Crowder! That has resolve the issue. I went with #1, and it's perfect! Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Cool explanation :), I too suspect `this` might not referring to the correct selector any more.

Comment: @Rohit416: It never referred to the *selector*, it referred to a DOM element. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are putting your code in the `success` function where `this` will be some sort of jQuery ajax object and not an HTML element.

You need to store `this` in a variable outside the ajax call and then use that variable.

e.g.

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
```

---

Then:

`setAttribute` is a DOM method, not a jQuery method.

Either:

```
$(that).attr("data-id", 5);
```

or (assuming `this` is a Element object):

```
that.setAttribute("data-id", 5);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Quentin - trying that, but no joy. I've added the whole method to my question.